# XSLT null comparison

Tags: xslt

I have an xml as below.

```
<attributes>
        <attribute>
            <attributeName>agenda-group</attributeName>
            <value>generic</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <attributeName>auto-focus</attributeName>
            <value>true</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <attributeName>no-loop</attributeName>
            <value>true</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <attributeName>salience</attributeName>
            <value>73</value>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
```

When i get the above  block i need to copy the above block as it is in resultant xml.If i get the below block with out values

```
   <attributes>
        <attribute>
            <attributeName></attributeName>
            <value></value>
        </attribute>

    </attributes>

         or
       <attributes/>
```

i need to omit this block in my resultant xml.I am using xslt for translation.
Please provide some pointers to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [identity template](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html#d5916e13) and add these templates:

```
<xsl:template match="attributes[not(attribute/value/text())]" />
<xsl:template match="attribute[not(value/text())]" />
```

These two empty templates catch `<attributes>` and `<attribute>` elements that have no value and produce no output for them, effectively removing them.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "attributes[not(node())]
 |
  attribute[not(attributeName/text())]
 "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (note the empty `<attributes>` and `attribute/attributeName` at the end):

```
<attributes>
    <attribute>
        <attributeName>agenda-group</attributeName>
        <value>generic</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attributeName>auto-focus</attributeName>
        <value>true</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attributeName>no-loop</attributeName>
        <value>true</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attributeName>salience</attributeName>
        <value>73</value>
    </attribute>

    <attribute>
        <attributeName></attributeName>
        <value></value>
    </attribute>

    <attributes/>
</attributes>
```

**produces the wanted result** (empty elements ignored -- not copied):

```
<attributes>
  <attribute>
    <attributeName>agenda-group</attributeName>
    <value>generic</value>
  </attribute>
  <attribute>
    <attributeName>auto-focus</attributeName>
    <value>true</value>
  </attribute>
  <attribute>
    <attributeName>no-loop</attributeName>
    <value>true</value>
  </attribute>
  <attribute>
    <attributeName>salience</attributeName>
    <value>73</value>
  </attribute>
</attributes>
```

**Explanation**: The identity rule (that copies every node "as-is") is overriden by a single template that matches the wanted "empty" elements and has no body, so that theye are simply skipped/ignored.

Comment: I'm not sure the input document required by the OP is as you have assumed. See my answer for my interpretation.

Comment: @empo: Yes, this is my interpretation of the question. A name-value pair is still meaningful if the value is empty/missing.

Answer (score 0):

The following transform will copy any `attributes` in the output, by omitting:

- empty `attributes`
- `attributes` with only empty `attribute` children (or with empty subelements)
- any empty children `attribute` (or with empty subelements)

XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="attributes[not(*)]
     |
     attributes[count(*)=count(attribute[.=''])]
     | 
     attribute[.='']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on the following input:

```
<root>
    <attributes>
        <attribute>
            <attributeName>agenda-group</attributeName>
            <value>generic</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute/>
        <attribute>
            <attributeName></attributeName>
            <value></value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <attributeName>salience</attributeName>
            <value>73</value>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
    <attributes>
        <attribute>
            <attributeName></attributeName>
            <value></value>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
    <attributes/>
</root>
```

produces:

```
<root>
   <attributes>
      <attribute>
         <attributeName>agenda-group</attributeName>
         <value>generic</value>
      </attribute>
      <attribute>
         <attributeName>salience</attributeName>
         <value>73</value>
      </attribute>
   </attributes>
</root>
```

Comment: I need to validate the xml based on the attributes tag.if the attributes tag is null i need to generate an exception using java in runtime.How to achieve the same. Please provide me some pointers.

Comment: @thog why did not tag the question with java then, adding also this detail?

Comment: @thog in your java app, for instance, you could use a single XPath expression (I think) to count unwanted attributes tag, and then generate the exception if `count>0`. Does it sound good?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//attributes[descendant::attribute]">
   some stuff
</xsl:for-each>
```